# filtering and grouping. with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the MoMa database provided in Github.
There are, for example, Artwork, Artist, Nationalities and Gender columns. I want to group artists by nationalities, but adding up and simplifying by continent and each continent subdivided by female and male artists. I created a list name each continent with its respective countries.

- I have tried to use pycountry, but somehow I just get error that module doesn't exist (even thought I installed it)
- I tried the .isin(), but for this it is also not appropriate
- I also tried .groupby(), but it also did not work.

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

this is the dataframe. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OUHu.png)

I expect a columns Continent , Gender, total
rows Continent name_ female
Continent name_ male

Continent/gender          total
latin america/female.     10
latin america/male.       11
latin amrica/nan
europe/female              14
europe/male.               20

and so on

the idea is to plot afterwards

Answer (score -1):

You got a nice intuition with the list of continents and countries. Canonical resolution of such a problem would usually consist in:

1. Obtain a table that relates countries (or nationalities in your case) with continents:

| Nationality | Continent |
| --- | --- |
| French | Europe |
| American | North America |
| Austrian | Europe |
| ... | ... |

2. Join this table to your original dataset. You should left join it into the main dataset, so you obtain a new dataset identical to the one of your picture, but with a Continent column.
3. Now that you have a continent column, you can perform the aggregation you are looking for. To do so, you have to group by continent **and** gender, and count the number of rows. Assuming you got the continent column in your dataframe, it would look like this:

   `df.groupby(['continent', 'gender']).count()`

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello Sergio, tks a lot for your help. I did it
I found two dataframes, one country and nationality and the other Country and Continent. Merged both left on Country. Then I merged the new dataframe to the moma one, also left and on = Nationality. It worked as I wished. Now it seems quite simple, but I spend days on it haha 
Now I just need to plot it. I guess Matplotlib is the way to go.